# "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' "

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert English Date to equivalent Nepali date.

When I run the code I get

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

This is my code:

```
from datetime import date
import datetime 
import time
import calendar

engMonth = int(input('Enter birth month in A.D.'))
engDate = int(input('Enter birth date in A.D.'))
engYear = int(input('Enter birth year in A.D.'))
```

Below is a List of no. of days in each month  of each year within a valid range

Nepali year-month List where, 2000, 2001, 2002 and so on are the Nepali years and 30, 32, 31 and so on are the total days in months

```
nepaliMonths = [
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],  #2000
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],  #2001
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],  #2071
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],  #2072
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 31 ],  #2073
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],  #2090
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 30, 31, 32, 32, 31, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 30, 30 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
            [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30 ]   #2099
        ]


#define the least possible English date 1944/01/01 Saturday.

startingEngYear = 1944
startingEngMonth = 1
startingEngDay = 1
dayOfWeek = calendar.SATURDAY  #1944 is a saturday


#Let's define the equivalent Nepali date 2000/09/17.

startingNepYear = 2000
startingNepMonth = 9
startingNepday = 17


# Let's calculate the number of days between the two English dates as follows:

date0=date(engYear,engMonth,engDate)
date1=date(startingEngYear,startingEngMonth,startingEngDay)
delta=date0 - date1
# print (delta.days)


#initialize required nepali date variables with starting  nepali date
nepYear = startingNepYear
nepMonth = startingNepMonth
nepDay = startingNepday
```

Error is in this block of code.

```
# decrement delta.days until its value becomes zero
while delta.days != 0:

    # getting total number of days in month nepMonth in a year nepYear
    daysInMonth = nepaliMonths.get(nepYear)[nepMonth]
    nepDay+=1 # incrementing nepali day

    if(nepDay > daysInMonth):
        nepMonth+=1
        nepDay = 1

    if(nepMonth > 12):
        nepYear+=1
        nepMonth = 1

    dayOfWeek+=1 #counting the days in terms of 7 days
    if(dayOfWeek > 7):
        dayOfWeek = 1

    delta.days-=1
```

Help

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive.  You don't access `list` with `get()`

Comment: You are using nepyear as an idex which is 2000 ... Even if you remove .get you still will run into idex out of range . issue is with your list of nepyear

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a [Python dictionary](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2015/08/30/python-dictionaries/)?

With a dictionary you could have something like this:

```
nepaliMonths = { 2000: [ 30, 32, 31, 32, 31, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30, 29, 31 ],
                 2001: [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30 ],

                 # Fill with rest of data . . .

                 2099: [ 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30 ] }
```

Then, to index your data set, simply use `nepaliMonths[year][month - 1]`

Example: `nepaliMonths[2000][0] == 30` and `nepaliMonths[2000][11] == 31`

**Another method**:

With your current implementation, you simply use `nepaliMonths[year - 2000][month - 1]`

Example: `nepaliMonths[0][0] == 30` and `nepaliMonths[0][11] == 31`

Answer (score 1):

`nepaliMonths` is a list, and indeed, lists do not have a `.get()` method.

Perhaps you meant `nepaliMonths[nepYear - startingNepYear][nepMonth]`?

Comment: @ JohnGordon I tried your way and got "IndexError: list index out of range" as error